# How to make avi (MJPEG codec) by avconv for iphone?

Tags: ios, avi, libav, mjpeg

I try to make video from pack of jpg by avconv and open it on iphone. I make avi file using MJPEG by command:

```
avconv -r 10 -i %06d.jpg -r 10 -vcodec mjpeg -qscale 1 out.avi
```

Eveything is ok on my PC, but when I open this video on iphone I see only black screen. I try to "convert"(by AVS Video Converter) it from MJPEG to MJPEG using all parametrs like in input file and iphone play it normally. I don't understand why video before "converting" is not playing on iphone. What I doing wrong?

PS info from avconv:

before "converting"

```
/mnt/dav $ avconv -i out.avi
avconv version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1+rpi1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 31 2013 13:58:10 with gcc 4.6.3
Input #0, avi, from 'out.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
  Duration: 00:00:02.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3767 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 1280x720, PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
At least one output file must be specified
```

after "converting"

```
/mnt/dav $ avconv -i out_conv.avi
avconv version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1+rpi1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 31 2013 13:58:10 with gcc 4.6.3
Input #0, avi, from 'out_conv.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:02.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3804 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
At least one output file must be specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the video has `yuvj422p` as pixel format, which uses 4:2:2 [chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling). It could be that the iPhone only supports 4:2:0 subsampling.

Try this instead:

```
avconv -r 10 -i %06d.jpg -r 10 -vcodec mjpeg -pix_fmt yuvj420p -qscale 1 out.avi
```